# How to add reference to a method parameter in javadoc?

Tags: java, arguments, javadoc

Is there a way to add references to one or more of a method's parameters from the method documentation body?
Something like:

```
/**
 * When {@paramref a} is null, we rely on b for the discombobulation.
 *
 * @param a this is one of the parameters
 * @param b another param
 */
void foo(String a, int b)
{...}
```

Answer (score 436, accepted):

As far as I can tell after reading [the docs for javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html) there is no such feature.

Don't use `<code>foo</code>` as recommended in other answers; you can use `{@code foo}`.  This is especially good to know when you refer to a generic type such as `{@code Iterator<String>}` -- sure looks nicer than `<code>Iterator&lt;String&gt;</code>`, doesn't it!

Comment: `@code` tag is described in [Javadoc - Tag Descriptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html).
See [Sample usage in JDK8 code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l172).

Comment: How is it not possible to reference a method's own parameters within the docs of the method. Swing and a miss, Java!

Answer (score 94):

The correct way of referring to a method parameter is like this:

[image]

Comment: Not only does it answer the question, but it visually explains how to amend Javadoc with a parameter using an IDE such as Intellij. This will be useful for searchers who are looking for an answer.

Comment: On Eclipse it doesn't work. But it's a nice answer nonetheless

Comment: this should be deleted. imagine no longer exists.

Comment: @user4504267 Image looks fine, at least now.

Comment: Try to refactor param name, intellij won't update this code blocks.

Comment: I just realized that the preview did not work for me since I was trying to refer one parameter from within the @param description of another instead of the javadoc body.

Comment: @m1ld That's because this simply formats the text as `code`. It does not actually link to the parameter name in any way, unlike the C# [paramref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xmldoc/paramref) tag.

Comment: Despite the pretty picture, ignore this answer and see the accepted answer from @kevin-bourrillion because it says to do the same thing but notes that it is only a workaround as no such feature exists (... and so you should not expect an actual link or for refactoring to update it etc.).

Answer (score 68):

As you can see in the Java Source of the `java.lang.String` class:

```
/**
 * Allocates a new <code>String</code> that contains characters from
 * a subarray of the character array argument. The <code>offset</code>
 * argument is the index of the first character of the subarray and
 * the <code>count</code> argument specifies the length of the
 * subarray. The contents of the subarray are copied; subsequent
 * modification of the character array does not affect the newly
 * created string.
 *
 * @param      value    array that is the source of characters.
 * @param      offset   the initial offset.
 * @param      count    the length.
 * @exception  IndexOutOfBoundsException  if the <code>offset</code>
 *               and <code>count</code> arguments index characters outside
 *               the bounds of the <code>value</code> array.
 */
public String(char value[], int offset, int count) {
    if (offset < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset);
    }
    if (count < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(count);
    }
    // Note: offset or count might be near -1>>>1.
    if (offset > value.length - count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(offset + count);
    }

    this.value = new char[count];
    this.count = count;
    System.arraycopy(value, offset, this.value, 0, count);
}
```

Parameter references are surrounded by `<code></code>` tags, which means that the Javadoc syntax does not provide any way to do such a thing. (I think String.class is a good example of javadoc usage).

Comment: The <code></code> tag is not referencing a specific parameter. It is formatting the word "String" into "code looking" text.

Comment: @Naxos84 that's true for the first <code></code> tag, but further on in the javadoc they reference `offset` and `count` parameters surrounded by <code></code> tags

Answer (score 14):

I guess you could write your own doclet or taglet to support this behaviour.

[Taglet Overview](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/taglet/overview.html)

[Doclet Overview](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html)

Comment: And make a pull request to javadoc :)

Answer (score -2):

Here is how it is written in Eclipse Temurin JDK 8 sources:

[image]

It looks like the only way is  or {@code }, but it's not a link - it's just formatting.

Comment: So.. other than under `Params:` section, where is `x` located in the javadoc description of `println` ?

Comment: This is an incorrect answer! `{@link #method(parameters)}` works only for a link to other methods of the same class, not to the parameters of the same method, which was the question.