# Refactorable reference to a method parameter in javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, javadoc

How do I make a reference, in javadoc, to a method parameter, so that the reference can be refactored ? 

For example:

```
public class A {

    private int field;

    /**
     * @param p 
     * {@link #field} is initialized using the value of p.
     */
    void foo(int p)
    {
        //...

    }
}
```

If I rename parameter p in the above code, I want

> "...using the value of p"

text to change accordingly (just as renaming field will change `{@link #field}` ). 

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1667212/3992939) old post, and some more sources, but could not find a way to do it.

Does javadoc support it ?

Comment: The Q&A you linked to states pretty clearly that there is no such feature in JavaDoc. Why should this question not be closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to Java erasure, method argument names are ephemeral, they are not part of the static class definition. So, `void foo(int p)` being changed to `void foo(int x)` is not considered refactoring, because it is guaranteed that it will not affect the program's logic in any way (unless the argument is overloading a class field).

So in the javadoc there cannot be a static link that identifies the method argument. The mere fact that the word after `@param` changes when you refactor the method is a favor offered by the IDE.

Comment: "[...] is not considered refactoring, because it is guaranteed that it will not affect the program's logic in any way"
Refactoring by definition does not affect the program's logic, only the structure, so it wouldn't be considered refactoring if it *did* affect the logic. I guess one could argue that renaming a parameter does not change the structure either, which I think might be what was meant here.

Answer (score 3):

Your IDE will be able to refactor the name if you put it after `@param` (tested in Eclipse), but not if you refer to it elsewhere within the comment.  From a language perspective, there's no reason to do this.  Why not just write `@param p {@link #field} is initialized using this value.`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I know that it will work for `@param p and some text` . It doesn't work for `some text @param p`

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDEA will refactor the parameter name anywhere in the JavaDoc comment as long as you place it in curly brackets, e.g. {@param p}

```
/**
 * @param p 
 * {@link #field} is initialized using the value of {@param p}.
 */
```

Also, Java's type erasure (as mentioned in the accepted response) has nothing to do with the scope of variable names. Type erasure is the compromise that Java designers implemented in order to add Java Generics but still keep the language backward compatible. All parameterization of generics is erased - none of it actually makes it to the byte code. This is why Java Generics are so limited - you can't for example do

```
T myT = new T();
```

if T is a parametrized type, because at runtime all information about T has already been erased.

Comment: He's not talking about generic type erasure, he's talking about erasure in general - and parameter names are indeed erased.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to configure eclipse javadoc preferences? *Window->Preferences, Java->Compiler->Javadoc*. Check the ***Process Javadoc comments*** option.

Also if you check *Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Typing->Javadoc and comment regions+**Add Javadoc tags*** it will add the appropiated javadoc tags. Once you have both activated Eclipse will warn you about the mistaken parameters and you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to "quick-fix" it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. These options are helpful. They do not help with the issue I raised.